# oauth2-proxy --logout-redirect-url problem with keycloak

Tags: nginx, keycloak, oauth2-proxy

I using keycloak and oauth2-proxy behind a NgInx server.
**keycloak: *24.x* / oauth2-proxy *7.6.0***

Here is my dockerfile (keycloak + oauth2-proxy are running in a docker container)

```
keycloak:
      build: .
      #image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2
      environment:
        KC_HOSTNAME: ${KC_HOSTNAME:-DOMAIN.de}
        KC_PROXY: edge
        KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH: /auth
        PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
       KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      command: start
      ports:
        - '8080:8080'
      depends_on:
        - postgres_db
      user: root  # Run the container with root user *This solved the issue!*

  oauth2-proxy:
      image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.6.0-alpine
      environment:
        OAUTH2_PROXY_BACKEND_LOGOUT_URL: "https://DOMAIN.de/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://DOMAIN.de/welcome&id_token_hint={id_token}"
        OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER: keycloak-oidc
        OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID: oauth2-proxy
        OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET: ${OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET}
        OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET: ${OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET}
        OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAINS: "*"
        OAUTH2_PROXY_EXTRA_JWT_ISSUER: "https://DOMAIN.de/auth/realms/master=asdf-client-credential"
        OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:4180"
        OAUTH2_PROXY_OIDC_ISSUER_URL: "https://DOMAIN.de/auth/realms/master"
        OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_ACCESS_TOKEN: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_USER_HEADERS: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_REDIRECT_URL: "https://DOMAIN.de/oauth2/callback"
        OAUTH2_PROXY_REVERSE_PROXY: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_SCOPE: "openid profile email"
        OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_XAUTHREQUEST: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_JWT_BEARER_TOKENS: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_SSL_INSECURE_SKIP_VERIFY: false
        OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_PROVIDER_BUTTON: true
        OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_CSRF_PER_REQUEST: 'true'
        OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_AUTH_HEADER: 'true'
      ports:
        - "4180:4180"
      depends_on:
        - keycloak
```

My NgInx Config is here:

```
server {
add_header 'X-Debug-Headers' '$http_x_auth_request_access_token';
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name mythicaltable.top www.mythicaltable.top; # managed by Certbot
        add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header x-auth-request-access-token "$http_x_auth_request_access_token";

        proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;
        proxy_buffers   4 512k;
        proxy_buffer_size   256k;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location /auth/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

                proxy_set_header Host  $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }

        location /welcome {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/welcome;
        }

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $request_uri;


        auth_request /oauth2/auth;
            error_page 401 = /oauth2/sign_in;       

                auth_request_set $user  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_user;
                auth_request_set $email  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_email;
                proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding *;

                proxy_set_header X-User  $user;
                 proxy_set_header X-Email $email;

                auth_request_set $token  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token;
                proxy_set_header X-Access-Token $token;

                auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
                add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

                # When using the --set-authorization-header flag, some provider's cookies can exceed the 4kb
                # limit and so the OAuth2 Proxy splits these into multiple parts.
                # Nginx normally only copies the first `Set-Cookie` header from the auth_request to the response,
                # so if your cookies are larger than 4kb, you will need to extract additional cookies manually.
                auth_request_set $auth_cookie_name_upstream_1 $upstream_cookie_auth_cookie_name_1;

                # Extract the Cookie attributes from the first Set-Cookie header and append them
                # to the second part ($upstream_cookie_* variables only contain the raw cookie content)
                if ($auth_cookie ~* "(; .*)") {
                        set $auth_cookie_name_0 $auth_cookie;
                        set $auth_cookie_name_1 "auth_cookie_name_1=$auth_cookie_name_upstream_1$1";
                }

                # Send both Set-Cookie headers now if there was a second part
                if ($auth_cookie_name_upstream_1) {
                        add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie_name_0;
                        add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie_name_1;
                }
        }

location /oauth2/ {
                proxy_pass http://oauth2_proxy;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $scheme://$host$request_uri;
        }
```

The Nginx logs show no errors. However, when I log out from Keycloak (DOMAIN.de/oauth2/sign_out) and use oauth2-proxy with its new --backend-logout-url property, the backend logs out but does not redirect to the post-logout-redirect-url. If I manually call the URL in the browser, it works. If I remove the id_token_hint from the --backend-logout-url, Keycloak throws an error because the id_token_hint is missing. This suggests to me that the --logout-backend-url is set and working, but there is no redirect happening.

Keycloak is configured like this:
[image]

and the **Backchannel logout session required** is true with logout URL `https://DOMAIN.de/oauth2/sign_out`

What can be the problem for the not working redirect after successfully logout?